# Calculate volume of $D$

Tags: real-analysis

> Evaluate the volume of 
>   $$D=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x^2 \le y\le 2, x \ge {{1} \over {2}} ,  0 \le z\le |\log(xy)| \right\}.$$

Should I consider the sign of $\log(xy)$, so I can divide interval of integration for $x$?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea!

Comment: The result is $49/24-(31/8)  \log2$?

Comment: You result is negative! It is wrong. Why don't you edit your question with your calculation (at least the first steps)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. In the first quadrant, $\log(xy)$ is positive above the curve $y=1/x$. Hence the volume of $D$ is given by
$$\int_{x=1/2}^1\left(\int_{y=x^2}^{1/x}-\ln(xy)dy\right)dx
+\int_{y=1}^2\left(\int_{x=1/y}^{\sqrt{y}}\ln(xy)dx\right)dy.$$

Comment: @Giulia B. Any progress with the integral?